# Problemas al consumir desde el eclipse las tareas del Bonita

Tags: java, bonita

Cuando trato de ejecutar una tarea manual en el Bonita desde el eclipse, me sale el siguiente error.

> POST
>   http://localhost:8080/bonita/serverAPI/org.bonitasoft.engine.api.ProcessAPI/updateActivityInstanceVariables
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> 2019-05-23 16:47:01,406 ERROR c.e.b.s.BPMService:206 - Exception
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.exception.UpdateException: USERNAME=usuario |
>   Some data does not exists, wanted to update [param1, param2] but there
>   is only []    at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.api.HTTPServerAPI.invokeMethod(HTTPServerAPI.java:128)
>     at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ClientInterceptor.invoke(ClientInterceptor.java:86)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.updateActivityInstanceVariables(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.example.bonita.service.BPMServiceImpl.updateProcess(BPMServiceImpl.java:144)
>     at
>   com.example.bonita.service.BPMServiceImpl.executeBPMTask(BPMServiceImpl.java:221)
>     at
>   com.example.bonita.service.BPMService.obtenerToken(BPMService.java:197)
>     at com.example.demo.Application.main(Application.java:209)  at  <
>   ========== Beginning of the server stack trace ========== >. ( )  at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ProcessAPIImpl.updateActivityInstanceVariables(ProcessAPIImpl.java:2617)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl.invokeAPI(ServerAPIImpl.java:462)
>     at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl$2.call(ServerAPIImpl.java:431)
>     at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.transaction.JTATransactionServiceImpl.executeInTransaction(JTATransactionServiceImpl.java:274)
>     at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl.invokeAPIInTransaction(ServerAPIImpl.java:438)
>     at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl.invokeAPI(ServerAPIImpl.java:272)
>     at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl.invokeMethod(ServerAPIImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.api.internal.servlet.HttpAPIServletCall.doPost(HttpAPIServletCall.java:111)
>     at
>   org.bonitasoft.engine.api.internal.servlet.HttpAPIServlet.doPost(HttpAPIServlet.java:35)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
>     at
>   org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mi codigo fuente es:

```
boolean resolved = false;
String result = "";

APISession apisession = bpmService.createLogin(username, password);

pendingTasks.clear();
pendingTasks = processAPI.getPendingHumanTaskInstances(apiSession.getUserId(), 0, 30, null);

for (Iterator<HumanTaskInstance> i = pendingTasks.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    HumanTaskInstance item = i.next();
    if (item.getRootContainerId() == request.getInstanceId()) {
        taskid = item.getId();
        processAPI.updateActivityInstanceVariables(taskid,    request.getVariables());

        resolved = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Mi archivo de propiedades es:

```
<BonitaProperties>
    <Name>bonita</Name>
    <Server>localhost</Server>
    <Port>8080</Port>
    <ProcessName>Proceso X</ProcessName>
    <ProcessVersion>1.0</ProcessVersion>
    <GenericUser>usuario</GenericUser>
    <GenericPwd>password</GenericPwd>
</BonitaProperties>
<profiles>
    <profile>member</profile>
</profiles>
```

Mi Pom es:

```
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>PermisosMatricula</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <bonita.bpm.version>7.8.4</bonita.bpm.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bonitasoft.engine</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonita-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bonitasoft.engine</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonita-server</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Mi versión del Bonita en Maven es 7.8.4 y utilizo Eclipse.

¿Tienen alguna idea de que puede ser?

Gracias.

Comment: Ingrid, bienvenida a Stack Overflow en Español. Gracias por preguntar y esperando poder ayudarte a resolver este problema te pido que edites tu pregunta agregando el contenido de tu archivo POM.xml o application.properties según sea el caso.

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida. Ya fue editado el comentario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya pude resolver este problema reemplazando el método "updateActivityInstanceVariables" por "executeUserTask(userId, taskid, listVariablesSerializable)".

Gracias.